# Probability of an n-digit number string match in two $6$-digit numbers

Tags: probability

I'm no mathematician, but I do have an amateur love of numbers. I've been having a discussion online with someone who is convinced that a 70% prevalence of the single digits 1,2,3,5,8 in six 6-digit numbers is statistically significant. I'm of the view that finding 50% of the available single digits 70% of the time in a small dataset has absolutely no significance. This did get me thinking though...

What is the probability of finding a matching string of n-digits in two randomly generated 6-digit numbers?

Comment: This would mean that we have at least $26$ out of $36$ with a $50-50$ chance. The probability for this is $0.0056655$ , which I would consider to be significant.

Comment: What has the probability of the match to do with the $70$% frequency of the $5$ digits ?

Comment: Could you explain your calculation re: the 5 digits? As I said, I'm not a mathematician so I'd be genuinely interested to understand why something that randomly occurs 50% of the time would be so unlikely to occur 70% of the time.

Comment: you haven't explained what you mean very well, could you give an example with actual numbers and explain  when it would or wouldn't match?  Are you saying 'generate a random number, what percentage of digits are from {1,2,3,5,8}?

Comment: My question really is to see how likely it would be for a string to be in common between two 6-digit numbers, as the numbers in question have no matching strings at all. My argument is that the numbers are randomly chosen, my friend's argument is that the six-digit strings are based around the numbers 1,2,3,5,8 by choice.

Comment: To further explain my question Cato - we have two random 6-digit numbers. What is the likelihood of them sharing, anywhere in them, a 2-digit sequence that is the same, or a 3-digit sequence that is the same .

Comment: Example: Number one is 123456. How likely is number two to contain any 2-digit sequence present in number one (12, 23, 34, 45, 56)

Comment: You need the binomial distribution to calculate the probability. A simpler estimation is the Ecart (also used in Roulette-theory) : Here , the Ecart is $\frac{26-10}{\sqrt{26+10}}\approx 2.67$. Ecarts larger than $2.5$ can be safely considered significant. Google normal distribution and standard deviation to get a feeling. The Ecart is basically the number of standard deviations, the observation deviates from the expected value.

Comment: I may be able to do that with a computer

Comment: Thanks Peter.  Does the fact that we're drawing from such a small pool of possible variables not have relevance? Or the fact that the dataset is so small?

Comment: Do you mean exactly two same or at least two same ? Or (two or three ) same ?

Comment: At least, thanks true blue

Comment: I still do not understand what the frequency should have to do with the probability of a match between two six-digit numbers. Which kind of match do you mean ?

Comment: Sorry if I've been confusing Peter! The 70% frequency is essentially the answer to the question I'm asking for single digits, that is the frequency of single digits from the number 558312 appearing in six other 6-digit numbers. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry true blue, the question is the same. What is the probability of any 2-digit string from one 6-digit number appearing in another, in any position, at least once.

Comment: It took this comment section for me to discover what I was actually asking! Thanks all for your input so far. Should I post a new question?

Comment: the probability is dependent on the first number, so 666666 is less likely to have a match, since it only matches if 66 is in the 2nd number

Comment: Interesting point Cato, thank you.  The first number is the only one I know.  It is 558312